# PySpark read gzip of multiple json file Failed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have no issue in reading a standalone JSON file which consists of a single line in the format of `{xxx...}`. However, when I compress it using `tar -zcvf` into one-file.json.gz and attempt to read it, I receive a single column named

```
root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
```

This code to read that gzip file.

```py
df = (
    spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")
    .json("../../one-file.json.gz")
)
```

When I try to use Aws Glue, it have some exceptions like:

> "Failure Reason": "Unable to parse file: one-file.json.gz\n"

I want to know what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple. The spark can only read json format data and .json.gz is not json. You have to untar the file before it is read by spark. You can use the tarfile module to do it like:

```
import tarfile
tar_file = tarfile.open("*.tar.gz")
tar_file.extractall()
spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").json(tar_file)
tar_file .close()
```

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean if I run `gzip example.json`, it will work.  But we need to bundle millions small json come from IOT device. Maybe need to seek other ways...

Comment: Is json ziped? If so, just create a batch to unzip each json and then bundle them

Comment: We're faced with the challenge of archiving millions of small JSON files within a folder and saving them in S3, while still making them accessible for Spark to perform some preprocessing. Currently, we're exploring the possibility of using Hadoop Archive or something similiar for this purpose.

Comment: Ok. The strategy I have given in this post works in your scenario. You can zip all the json files in a folder to save the space. When they need to be accessed by Spark, add the python code to unzip them first.